# Find the smallest number that is greater than a given number in a sorted list

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

Given a sorted list of numbers, I need to find the smallest number that is greater than a given number. Consider this list:

---

```
arr=[1,2,3,5,7,11,101,131,151,181,191,313,353,373,383]
```

Say the specified number is 320. Then, my method should return 353 as 353 is the smallest number greater than 320.

I am trying to use a slightly modified form of binary search; however on execution the program goes into infinite loop.

---

```
def modBinarySearch(arr,x):
    l=len(arr)
    mid=l/2
    if arr[mid]>=x and arr[mid-1]<x:
        return arr[mid]
    elif arr[mid]>x and arr[mid-1]>x:
        modBinarySearch(arr[mid:l],x)
    else: 
        modBinarySearch(arr[0:mid],x)

N=int(raw_input())
arr=[1,2,3,5,7,11,101,131,151,181,191,313,353,373,383]
print modBinarySearch(arr,N)
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If arr[mid] and arr[mid-1], both are greater than your number, you should search in arr[0:mid], don't you think?

```
 elif arr[mid]>x and arr[mid-1]>x:
    modBinarySearch(arr[0:mid],x)
else: 
    modBinarySearch(arr[mid:1],x)
```

Comment: You _still_ need to return the values from your recursive calls rather than just throwing that information away. Without that, it doesn't really matter what the rest of the code does. In addition, you're using `1` (wun) where you should be using `l` (ell).

Answer (score 11):

There is a standard module, [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html), that does this already:

```
In [49]: arr[bisect.bisect(arr, 320)]
Out[49]: 353
```

I think this should be the go-to method for searching sorted lists. There are a few [examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists) in the manual.

As to your implementation, there is a number of problems:

1. Your recursion doesn't handle small arrays correctly.
2. The slicing done in the second branch is incorrect.
3. Your function doesn't return anything.
4. Because `arr` is in ascending order, `arr[mid]>x and arr[mid-1]>x` is equivalent to `arr[mid-1]>x`, suggesting you didn't write what you meant

Last but not least, recursion and all that slicing are completely unnecessary for this problem.

Comment: This gives this message in Python 2.7 :`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    arr[bisect.bisect(arr, 320)]
NameError: name 'bisect' is not defined`

Comment: @CSSS: Have you imported the `bisect` module?

Comment: No.. I haven't.. will try that

Answer (score 6):

If the size of your lists is going to be 15, ditch the binary search altogether and use a sequential search.

You'll find the code much easier to write and, unless you need to do it many millions of times per second, the sequential solution will be more than fast enough.

If you *do* need to stick with the binary search, your *first* step should be to actually return the results of your recursive calls.

Answer (score 3):

```
def modBinarySearch(arr, n):
    m = len(arr) / 2

    if arr[m] >= n and arr[m - 1] < n:
        return arr[m]
    elif arr[m] > n and arr[m - 1] > n:
        return modBinarySearch(arr[:m], n)
    else:
        return modBinarySearch(arr[m:], n)


arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 313, 353, 373, 383]
n = 320
print(modBinarySearch(arr, n))
```

Answer (score 2):

python 3.2

```
next(i for  i in arr if i>320)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [bisect module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) is your best choice for this:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

arr=[1,2,3,5,7,11,101,131,151,181,191,313,353,373,383]


def find_lt(a, x):
    'Find rightmost value less than x'
    i = bisect_left(a, x)
    if i:
        return a[i-1]
    raise ValueError

def find_gt(a, x):
    'Find leftmost value greater than x'
    i = bisect_right(a, x)
    if i != len(a):
        return a[i]
    raise ValueError

print find_lt(arr,320)          
print find_gt(arr,320)
```

prints

```
313
353
```

Answer (score 0):

IF the list is sorted:

```
x = range(20)
N= 15

for i in x:
    if i>N:
        print i
        break
```

Gives 16.

If using numpy:

```
x = np.arange(20)
N = 15
x[x>15][0]
```

Gives 16.

If you were looking for easy implementations, for your specific problem, let me get back on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def modBinarySearch(arr,x):
    l=len(arr)
    mid=l/2
    if arr[mid] >= x and arr[mid-1] < x:
        return arr[mid]
    elif arr[mid]>x and arr[mid-1]>x:
        num = modBinarySearch(arr[0:mid],x)
    else:
        num = modBinarySearch(arr[mid:l],x)
    return num

N=int(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
arr=[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 313, 353, 373, 383]
print modBinarySearch(arr,N)
```